# Generating sound with VCO

Tags: voltage, analog, sound, vco

I have an extremely basic electronics experience (op amps, filters...not much past that) and need to generate sound from a varying voltage voltage signal. I simply want it to increase in frequency/pitch as voltage amplitude increases. Can this be accomplished with simply running the output into VCO and a speaker? What additional components would I need?

Answer (score 3):

This should work provided you can find a VCO that would operate in the audible range (20Hz-20kHz), as they typically operate at much higher frequencies. Depending on the driving strength and the output voltage of the VCO you may have to add a buffer/amplifier to drive a speaker.

Comment: Could also divide down the VCO's output to get to audio range.

Answer (score 0):

you could use IC555 configured as vco [refer this link](http://techtrill.blogspot.in/2012/01/vco-using-ic-555.html)

Answer (score 0):

Most audio VCOs that you might be looking at will not effectively drive a speaker. You could try using an [LM380](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDQQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fds%2Fsymlink%2Flm380.pdf&ei=7NVkUuXPKsi00QWv5IGADQ&usg=AFQjCNGWTOxDVE0rUybi3civZS2jp_GmPQ&bvm=bv.54934254,d.d2k) on the output. It's a 2W audio amp and fairly commonly available.

If you could specify the VCO circuit and power supplies more guidance could be given.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea will work, though as other answers have said, you will need additional amplification to drive a speaker.

But one point worth mentioning is the relationship between voltage and frequency or pitch. Frequency is measured in Hz, and a VCO usually has a (roughly) linear relationship between voltage and frequency.

However pitch is usually described in semitones or octaves, where an octave is a doubling in frequency, i.e. there is an exponential relationship between pitch and frequency.

This matters if your application is a musical instrument, because it is convenient to arrange a linear relationship between voltage and pitch (e.g. 1V/octave = 1/12V per semitone), which means an exponential relationship between voltage and frequency.

So if this is a musical instrument like an analog synth, you probably need to process your input voltage, via an [antilog amplifier](https://www.google.com/search?q=antilog%20amplifier), before feeding it to the VCO.